# Multisite htaccess on localhost with WP as an SVN external?

Tags: multisite, htaccess, apache

I've mimicked [Otto's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) setup here: http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-wordpress-site-using-svn/ and my brief example is below.

That tutorial is specific to a single site install, and specifies a single domain. **How can I customize the `htaccess` below to be suitable for multisite?** Note that the multisite `htaccess` WordPress provides doesn't work because the `wp` directory is custom.

**Directory Setup**

- `C:\wamp\www\my_site` - Site root
- `C:\wamp\www\my_site\wp-config.php` - Config
- `C:\wamp\www\my_site\wp` - WordPress as an SVN external
- `C:\wamp\www\my_site\custom-content` - Custom content dir

**Apache Setup**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/my_site"
    ServerAdmin me@example.com

    <Directory C:/wamp/www/my_site>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]
```

Comment: why do you want wordpress in a custom dir `/wp/`?

Comment: So that when I commit my project to SVN WordPress core files are totally independent of my plugins and themes. As an external I can switch WP versions on the fly.

Comment: do you switched 'wp-content' with 'custom-content' so that you store your themes,plugins,uploads there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, this is unsolvable according to Mark Jaquith, [as noted here](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton).

> **Q**: Does this support WordPress in multisite mode?
>
> **A**: No. Not until
> WordPress supports WordPress-in-a-subdirectory installation for
> multisite. If you're a WordPress hacker who wants to help with that
> feature, drop me a line

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly relevant, but [Before You Create A Network: WordPress_Settings_Requirements](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#WordPress_Settings_Requirements) says

> [Giving WordPress its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) will not work in WordPress 3.0 with multisite enabled. If you wish to install WordPress in a folder AND have that folder name it will work. Domain mapping, however, will not work.

I'm not sure what *AND have that folder name* means there.

Comment: I think this is referring to the situation where you might want `example.com/wordpress/`. In my case, I don't need/want the WordPress directory name public like that. I think my desired solution is reachable, but I just don't know enough about `htaccess`.